# Expose a Java Service Provider Interface to Service Providers

Tags: java, service-provider

I'm trying to create a framework for plugin/apps, and I think I've settled on using a Service Provider Interface (SPI) in Java to achieve that. The ultimate vision is that people can download plugins (like an app store) and then just drop the jars into a folder, and they'll work with the existing program.

So I have a class `PluginInterface` that will be my SPI. I want all plugins to implement this class (it has basic methods like `doesAccept`, `handle`, etc.). Since 3rd parties will be creating the Service Providers, **how can I let them reference this Java interface in their code (so they can implement it), without actually giving them the source code of the main application?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two JARs api and impl where you put your application in the impl  and put whatever the code you need to share with third party developer in api.

Example: jaxb-api.jar and jaxb-impl.jar

Comment: Any idea how I can create a jar with just some selected code (in Intellij or in command line)?

Comment: You need to create a multi-maven project. Where you have two project api and impl.

Comment: Maven is not a mandatory option in Java, but this is not the topic ;-) In order to package properly your JARS, the point is to respect [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html)...

Comment: For example, the jaxb-impl.jar should contain a *META-INF/services* folder with appropriates files to specify the implemented interface(s).

Comment: In your case you should have a single text file named after the interface: *META-INF/services/PluginInterface*. In the content is a single line with the full name of the implementing class...